# Determine offset where the most constructive interference occurs

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, waveform

I have two arrays of data:

[image]

I would like to align these similar graphs together (by adding an offset to either array):

[image]

Essentially what I want is the most constructive interference, as shown when two waves together produce the same wave but with larger amplitude:

[image]

This is also the same as finding the most destructive interference, but one of the arrays must be inverted as shown:

[image]

Notice that the second wave is inverted (peaks become troughs / vice-versa).

The actual data will not only consist of one major and one minor peak and trough, but of many, and there might not be any noticeable spikes. I have made the data in the diagram simpler to show how I would like the data aligned.

I was thinking about a few loops, such as:

```
biggest = 0
loop from -10 to 10 as offset
    count = 0
    loop through array1 as ar1
        loop through array2 as ar2
            count += array1[ar1] + array2[ar2 - offset]
    replace biggest with count if count/sizeof(array1) > biggest
```

However, that requires looping through offset and looping through both arrays. My real array definitions are extremely large and this would would take too long.

How would I go about determining the offset required to match data1 with data2?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLy6z/) (note that this is language agnostic and I would like to understand the algorithm more-so than the actual code)

Comment: Probably finding the highest and lowest elements in both arrays, and comparing their indices.

Comment: @SecondRikudo this will obviously fail in common case. Very unlikely that this issue can be solved in less that `O(n)` without additional data-structures.

Comment: @SecondRikudo In a more complex array, there will be duplicates. Many low and high values will collide with each other.

Comment: This isn't an area I'm familiar with (and I suppose there is literature about it). However, since the streams aren't identical, and since performance is important, I would try experimenting with some randomized approach (e.g. select K random representative points, and then find the optimal offset by looking for the minimal delta of these k points when sliding them along the complete stream. This process can be repeated T times, to increase confidence).

Comment: it looks like one of the most basics problems of map matching algorithms. try to search there

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and [Cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) an its computation using [Fast Fourier Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast%5fFourier%5ftransform). It's the way how it is done in real life applications.

Comment: If the only tool you know is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: Snark aside, this problem looks like a nail because it *is* a nail.

Answer (score -1):

If (and only if) you data has very recognizeable spikes, you could do, what a human being would do: Match the spikes: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkRZ2/)

the importand part is `function matchData()`

An improved version would search for N max and min spikes, then calculate an average offset.

Comment: People should know a little bit from [Cybernetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybernetics) instead of giving stupid advises. Knowing only computers is useless.

Comment: Thank you for this approach. This is what I had initially tested but realized my data does not have spikes // has spikes everywhere. I have edited my question to clarify this. When combining the arrays, the result should have an overall higher peak and lower trough than both arrays alone.